# Heroku + mongolab sandbox app deployment in play store

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I have recently started working on android apps. i have used nodejs as the server for the REST API. I have now finished developing my android app. I want to put it into Play store.

Can i go ahead with the free Heroku account that i have which hosts my nodejs and mongolab with sandbox that holds my database? Will my app be allowed if i have these serving my app on play store?

I have tried googling but have not found a conviencing answer. eagerly waiting for your answers! Please help me get through! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There s not much of approval in google play store. you just need to make sure that you follow [this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html) guid lines.

so in short yes, your app wont get rejected as long as it doesnt have any other reason too.